# Paramaterless Constructor Error when configuring Ninject to work with Web API 2 and OWIN

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, ninject, owin

I am working with Web API 2 and OWIN, and trying to wire up Ninject, but I can't seem to get the app to get past the App_Startup when starting the api without running into this error,

```cs
[MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.]
System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +113
System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +206
System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +83
System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +11
Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.MakeDelegate(Type type, String methodName, IList`1 errors) +250
Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.LoadImplementation(String startupName, IList`1 errorDetails) +212
Owin.Loader.DefaultLoader.Load(String startupName, IList`1 errorDetails) +32
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinBuilder.GetAppStartup() +125
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.InitializeBlueprint() +53
System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore(T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory) +115
System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory) +72
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context) +96
System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +534
System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +339
System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +296

[HttpException (0x80004005): No parameterless constructor defined for this object.]
System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9946132
System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +90
System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +261
```

In addition to Ninject, I installed Ninject.Web.WebApi, Ninject.Web.WebApi.OwinHost, Ninject.Web.Common, and Ninject.Web.Common.OwinHost. After stepping through the launch of the app, it seems to be working all the way up until it hits

```cs
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;
```

Here is the NinjectWebCommon.cs file that I am using,

```cs
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof (NinjectWebCommon), "Start")]
[assembly: ApplicationShutdownMethod(typeof (NinjectWebCommon), "Stop")]

namespace MyApp.App_Start
{
    public static class NinjectWebCommon
    {
        private static readonly Bootstrapper Bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();
        public static void Start()
        {
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));

            IKernel container = null;
            Bootstrapper.Initialize(() =>
            {
                container = CreateKernel();
                return container;
            });

            var resolver = new NinjectDependencyResolver(container);
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;
        }
        public static void Stop()
        {
            Bootstrapper.ShutDown();
        }
        private static IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            try
            {
                kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
                kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

                RegisterServices(kernel);
                return kernel;
            }
            catch
            {
                kernel.Dispose();
                throw;
            }
        }
        private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            var containerConfigurator = new NinjectConfigurator();
            containerConfigurator.Configure(kernel);
        }

    }
}
```

Note that the,

```cs
containerConfigurator.Configure(kernel);
```

function in the `RegisterServices` method is calling this,

```cs
 namespace MyApp.App_Start
{
    public class NinjectConfigurator
    {
        public void Configure(IKernel container)
        {
            AddBindings(container);
        }
        private void AddBindings(IKernel container)
        {
            container.Bind<MyContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
            container.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().ToMethod(ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<TimelyContext>());
            container.Bind<DbContext>().ToMethod(ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<TimelyContext>())
                .WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", "MyDb");
            container.Bind<IUserService>().To<UserService>();
            container.Bind<IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider>().To<SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider>();
        }
    }
}
```

and the resolver for `NinjectDependencyResolver` method before the global configuration dependency resolver is set is defined here,

```cs
 namespace MyApp.App_Start
{
    public class NinjectDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
    {
        private readonly IKernel _container;
        public NinjectDependencyResolver(IKernel container)
        {
            _container = container;
        }

        public IKernel Container
        {
            get
            {
                return _container;
            }
        }
        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            return _container.TryGet(serviceType);
        }
        public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
        {
            return _container.GetAll(serviceType);
        }
        public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
        {
            return this;
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
}
```

I got this Ninject boiler code from ASP.NET Web API 2 book by Jamie Kurtz and Brian Wortman.

I'm pretty lost on this one, and haven't found any posts that have helped me figure this one out. Any suggestions are helpful, and please ask questions for clarity. Thanks!